How to fill inputs on page from Chrome extension values?
I am creating an extension which takes in values, and fills it onto a page only when I click the submit button on the extension. I am having trouble getting the popup to communicate with the page with my submit function. I was able to get the form filled with chrome.action.onClicked.addListener but could not get it working on button click from the extension popup.
This is the example site to test the extension on:
https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields. I am targeting the first name (02frstname).
/* index.html */
<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label for="f_name">Fist name</label>
      <input name="f_name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="l_name">Last name</label>
      <input name="l_name" />
    </div>
    <button id="submit-btn" type="button">Fill values</button>
  </form>
  <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

/* contentScript.js */
const submit = document.getElementById("submit-btn");

submit.addEventListener("click", async () => {

  const fnameInput = document.getElementsByName("02frstname");
  fnameInput[0]?.value = "example";
});

/* manifest.json */ 
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Form example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": { "default_popup": "index.html"},
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
      
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting", "storage"]
}
*/


You have confused the content script with the popup script. 1) Remove content_scripts, 2) Rename contentScript.js to script.js 3) Use chrome.scripting.executeScript inside the click listener as shown in these examples. 4) You may need to use document.execCommand (example) inside executeScript.

@wOxxOm I got it working thanks to your direction
